# How to enable cluster or hybrid mode in Puma and what are they?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, heroku

The readme at https://github.com/schneems/puma_worker_killer says `Puma worker killer can only function if you have enabled cluster mode or hybrid mode (threads + worker cluster). If you are only using threads (and not workers) then puma worker killer cannot help keep your memory in control.`

So if I'm using [puma](https://github.com/puma/puma) on heroku, how do I tell if cluster or hybrid mode is enabled, given that in the [puma readme](https://github.com/puma/puma) it only talks about clustered mode?

How do I enable cluster mode?  How do I enable hybrid mode?

Is that simply done by specifying the number of workers in config/puma.rb in your Rails app's config folder?

Answer (score 1):

Hybrid mode or Cluster mode are the same. Yes you need to specify the number of worker. You will need at least 2 workers to call it to be a cluster. Generally the number of workers depend up on the number for core's your processor has.

Comment: It would be great to get a more detailed response for this answer.